# Organizing csv export with scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

For exporting my data to a CSV file, I'm currently using (mainly because I never understood pipelines that well):

```
custom_settings = {

    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI' : 'datosAmazon.csv'

}
```

This custom settings are inside my spider.

Right now, I'm scraping different categories of items, for example, laptops and cell phones.

Problem is that, when I go check out my data, things are not organized, maybe a laptop appears, then a cell phone, then 2 laptops, cellphone and so on.

I'm currently going into different categories this way

```
def start_requests(self):

    keywords = ['laptop', 'cellphone']

    for keyword in keywords:

        yield Request(self.search_url.format(keyword))
```

Is it there a way for the data to be more organized (2 files would be even better), or an easy pipeline solution.

Comment: One thing you can do is to save data related to different categories to different dictionaries and then using csvreader module, save these dictionaries to different csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no settings-only way to achieve what you want.

That said, exporting to multiple files from a custom pipeline is pretty straight-forward:

- Create multiple exporters (`scrapy.exporters.CSVItemExporter`) in the `open_spider` method (probably store them in a dict)
- Select the correct exporter (based on the item) in the `process_item` method and call its `export_item`
- Close the files in the `close_spider` method

Don't forget to activate your pipeline :)